# Calculating Items of a listbox which has a Databinding

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox1 (in C# winforms) which is FilledBy a DataBindingSource (its a sqlite.db).

```
// 
// listBox1
// 
this.listBox1.DataSource = this.itemWerteBindingSource;
this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Frage-Nr";
this.listBox1.FormatString = "N0";
this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(113, 225);
this.listBox1.TabIndex = 15;
```

The Form_Load event is:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.item_WerteTableAdapter.Fill(this.erhebungenDataSet.Item_Werte);
}
```

Being compiled the (Items/Values) Numbers (1 2 3) of the Data row are shown correctly in listbox1

The Button_Click event for showing the results in labels is:

```
private void btnresultB1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are no items in the listbox");
                return;
            }

            double sum = 0;

            foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDouble(item.ToString());
//Here comes the FormatException
             }

            int count = listBox1.Items.Count;
            double average = sum / count;
            lbcount.Text = count.ToString();
            lbsum.Text = sum.ToString();
            lbavg.Text = average.ToString();
        }
```

The Items of the listbox1 are count but not calculated - Format Exception. When I send the Data to another listbox2

```
    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

listbox2 doesnt show the Data (1 2 3), but "System.Data.DataRowView". So, I obviously have a Problem with the Values of the Items in listbox1 which can´t be interpreted / converted. I tried it with decimal instead of double - same Format Exception.

I dont want to let the db (sqlite) do the calculation.

I´m rather new in programming. How can I calculate such a data bound listbox? Conversion to generic list doesn´t work also. If put some Numbers into listbox2 and change the button event to listbox2 everything works fine. I found no answers in days of searching and trying. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to show more code like what your datasource you are binding to, is it an array of integers, composite objects etc.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for being late. Changed the question - hope it´s better to understand. The DataType of the row in the Datasource is Double, the values are 1 2 3. It also doesn´t work if it´s Type is decimal. What do I not know - what do I have to look for? Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because your object's ToString function is returning the string "DataRowView", which is not a number you can use.  A cast is required:

```
sum += Convert.ToDouble(((DataRowView)item)["Frage-Nr"]);
```

It *probably* makes more sense to work with the data source directly, in which case, you can try this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ((DataTable)itemWerteBindingSource.DataSource).Rows) 
{
  sum += Convert.ToDouble(dr["Frage-Nr"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Lars. Your first solution works perfect and is exactly what I was looking for, needed - the correct cast. Working dircetly with the datasource throws the exception, that the Objekt of Type "Test.Data.DataSet.ErhebungenDataSet" could not be converted to "System.Data.DataTable", but I can continue with your first solution, thanks again.

Comment: @GuGri If the DataSource is a DataSet, then you would have to select the DataTable inside the DataSet.

Comment: Got it - solution 2 now also works fine. Thank you so much, Lars            foreach (DataRow dr in (erhebungenDataSet.Item_Werte).Rows) 
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Frage-Nr"]);
            }